# pairs of prime and composite in a range

Tags: c++, algorithm, math

I need to find no. of ways of selecting a pair of prime number (p) and a composite number (q) in a given range .
l<=p,q<=r
Input : -

First line contains integer T ,no. of testcases.

Next T  lines contains two space integers l and r.

Output : -

Each test case has one output , no. of pairs of prime number and a composite number in new line.

constraints
1<=T<=10^5
1<=l,r<=10^5

i have written a code using sieve algorithm but its not working for some cases...(eg case 1 to 100000)
and for some it is showing timeout.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int* sievealgo(){

    int* A=new int[100005];
    A[0]=A[1]=1;
    for(long long i=2;i*i<=100004;i++){

        if(A[i]==0){
            for(int j=i*i;j<=100004;j+=i){
                A[j]=1;
            }
        }

    }
    return A;
}

int main() {

    int n,x,l,r;
    int *A;
    cin>>n;
    A=sievealgo();

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        int count=0;
        cin>>l;
        cin>>r;
        for(int i=l;i<=r;i++){
            if(A[i]==0) count++;
        }
        cout<<(r-l+1-count)*count<<endl;
    }

}
```

Comment: You should use some faster algorithm like "cumulative sum" technique instead of looping for every query.

Comment: `int* A=new int[100005]` leaves the array uninitialized, containing random garbage. `sievealgo` assumes the array is initialized to all zeros, but it isn't. So you don't even have a correct list of primes.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik can you elaborate your point further as I didn't get it. Thank you.

Comment: Print the contents of `A` right after `int* A=new int[100005];` line. I expect values other than 0 to be printed. Whereas the function clearly expects that `A[i] == 0` for all `i` after this line.

Answer (score 0):

Your program is too slow because you are using nested loop. When the input is

```
100000
1 100000
(99999 more "1 100000" lines)
```

Your program will take about 10^10 steps and it is too large for non-parallel programs run on present day computers.

Instead of that, you should

1. Allocate another array (say, `count`)

2. Have the array hold numbers of prime numbers in 0 to the index (inclusive)

```
index:  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  ...
A    :  1  1  0  0  1  0  1  0  1  1  ...
count:  0  0  1  2  2  3  3  4  4  4  ...
```

You can do that by

1. initializing `count[0]` to `0`
2. for each elements with positive indice `i`, set `count[i]` to `count[i-1]` if `A[i] != 0` (not prime) and `count[i-1]+1` if `A[i]==0` (prime)

3. Now the number of prime numbers between `l` and `r` (both inclusive) is `count[r] - count[l-1]`

Also, as @IgorTandetnik pointed out,

```
int* A=new int[100005];
```

don't do initialization of elements, so you should manually assign 0 to each elements before the sieving.

Quote from [N3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf):

5.3.4 New 15

> If the new-initializer is omitted, the object is default-initialized (8.5);
> if no initialization is performed, the object has indeterminate value.

8.5 Initializers 6

> To default-initialize an object of type T means:
>
> - if T is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type (Clause 9), the default constructor for T is called   (and the initialization is ill-formed if
>   T has no accessible default constructor);
> - if T is an array type, each element is default-initialized;
> - otherwise, no initialization is performed.

Now `int` is class nor an array, no initialization is performed and the value is indeterminate.